# Ajax display reCaptcha, grecaptcha is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax, recaptcha

In ajax request, try to load recaptcha script (version 2.0) using ajax and display the recaptcha.

```
jQuery.ajax({type: "GET", 
   url: "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&hl=en", 
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      grecaptcha.render('my-captcha-div',
              {sitekey:'a-site-key',
               theme:'light'});
   },
   dataType: "script",
   cache: true});
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

Thanks.